What rounding method to use for JPEG encoder FDCT and Quantizer
I am designing a JPEG Encoder. The FDCT and Quantization steps involve fixed point maths. After the result is generated it needs to be scaled down and rounded to integer. The question is, what rounding method should I use? There are many rounding methods and it is not clear which one is most suitable for an image compression design.
Here are some examples: round towards zero, round away from zero, round half up, round half down, round half even, round half odd.
The design is implemented in hardware in RTL (VHDL) and shall run on FPGA. So this is not a software question.
